# What does "let" do in Rust?

Tags: rust

Two questions mainly:

1. How `let x = y` is translated to pseudo-english/pseudo-code?
2. How does the `if let x = y {}` block work in step-by-step?

---

Always assumed *let* declares a variable, until I met *if let* (code below), and went Googling.

```rust
let config_max = Some(3u8);
if let Some(max) = config_max {
    println!("The maximum is configured to be {}", max);
} else {
    println!("xyz");
}
```

StackOverflow threads explained that ***let* actually evaluates/checks a pattern**. So I understood it as that let only checks if pattern and value match, and doesn't declare the variable by itself:

```rust
let y = Some(5);
if let Some(x) = y { doZ(x); }
// 1. let Some(x) = y -- see if pattern Some(x) matches value y, if yes execute next expression
// 2. Some(x) = y -- the next expression, assign value of y to "variable Some(x)"
// if ( 1 and 2 are successful) { execute this }
```

But then, if *let* is only used for pattern-value matching/evaluation, then why is it used in a variable declaration?
Answer: Because it is NOT only used for pattern matching, and is needed for a variable declaration.

```rust
let y = Some(5);
if let Some(x) = y { doZ(x); }
// if -- if
// let Some(x) = y -- ( if pattern Some(x) matches Some(5), declare variable Some(x) and assign value Some(5) to it ) 
// doZ(x) -- { execute doZ function and pass x as an argument}
```

a - Does the above "translation" mean that `let Some(x) = Some(5)` == `let x = 5`? If yes how does that happen? b - Isn't the whole point of types of `Option<T>` and `Enum` is to be different from raw `T`?

```rust
if let x = 5 { doZ(x); } // a
// Warning: x = 5 is irrefutable, consider using just "let" without "if".

5 == Some(5) // b, false
```

The above error also refutes if `if` in `if let Some(x) = y` is a regular if, looking for a bool value, after which it will run the code inside the "{}". But `let` is a statement, it doesn't return a bool or anything, with or without the `if`. So does that mean `if` in this specific case is not actually an `if` (which needs a bool to execute a code), but a in-exhausting `match`? If yes, why `if` and not some other/new keyword?

Comment: Your last 'error' isn't an error, it's a warning, that `if` isn't needed.

Comment: `let` by itself also does pattern matching, just only irrefutable ones. @cadolphs

Comment: Very good clarification, yes. This is great for things like tuple unpacking.

Comment: @cadolphs, so `if let` can't declare a variable?

Comment: @Bookworm: It does declare variables as part of the unpacking process; `if let Some(x) = y { ... }` is, in the process of pattern-matching, declaring `x`, should the pattern match succeed.

Comment: Try re-reading chapter 18 of The Book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-00-patterns.html. It's explained pretty good here, especially in 18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `let` by itself is just variable assignment (possibly with pattern matching, if the pattern is irrefutable).
2. `if` by itself is branching based on a bool value
3. `if let` isn't just some weird mishmash of `let` and `if` but a separate construction:

What does `if let` do? It tries to match a value to a pattern and in doing so binds parts of the value to the pattern that is being matched. Only if the pattern actually matches successfully will it then execute the code in the `if let` block:

```rust
let x = 5; // simple variable assignment

let (x, y) = (3, 4); // assignment with pattern matching

if x % 2 == 0 { // only do this code if number is even
  println!("x is even");
}

// if let to do pattern-matching and assignment, 
// but where the pattern might potentially not match
if let Some(x) = function_that_returns_option() {
  println!("The function returned Some(x) with x = {}", x);
}

// if the function had returned None instead, then nothing would have been printed and nothing would have been assigned to that x.
```

Comment: Is it just an "accept as it is" thing or is there some other use cases for it? Why is it a thing? Why isn't it for example `matchLight Some(x) = optionReturn() { println!({x}) }`?

Comment: @Bookworm: Because it's generally a good thing to minimize unnecessary introduction of new keywords if you can avoid them without creating excessive complexity. Aside from your proposed keyword, `if let` *is* the "match light" you propose. `let` already does "can't fail" pattern-matching on its own (e.g. unpacking, as cadolphs shows), `if let` just extends that to "can fail" usage, where the controlled block only executes when the pattern-matching succeeds, so it's actually related to what `if` and `let` already do independently.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah ok, this your explanation makes much more sense, thanks!

Comment: @cadolphs nit: `let` by itself is just variable *declaration* e.g. `let foo;` Also since your comment is covering both `let` and `if let` it might be useful to cover `let else`.

Comment: @Bookworm FWIW there is [an `if let` RFC which you can read for a basic gist](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0160-if-let.html), and it links to the corresponding issues (in RFCs and Rust) where the proposals were discussed.

Comment: The Book states that simple `let` is also a pattern match: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements